# Is it possible to automatically change the multiple displays setting to "Duplicate" when a certain application is open?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

Currently, I have my laptop running Windows 10 hooked up to an external monitor and set to "Extend these displays".

[image]

However, I want to make it so that if a certain application is opened/is running, the above setting will change to "Duplicate these displays".

Is there a way to achieve this? I assume it will have to be done via an automation system like AutoHotKey, but I don't know how to do this or even if it's doable.

If it matters, the external monitor is hooked up via HDMI.

Comment: You can set the display mode with the built-in `displayswitch.exe /clone` to duplicate your screen, and `displayswitch.exe /extend` to extend your screen. Then it depends whether you want to add that to the application's startup command, or if you want a program like AHK to wait and listen for that specific application to start

Comment: WIN+P can also be used to switch between various modes. Press WIN+P a few times in a row to switch to a different mode, and just remember how many times you have to press it, the fastest way to switch if you don't want to automate it.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale amazing I didn't know that was even a built in thing! It works great! If you can post that as an answer, that'd be great since it wouldn't require a 3rd party tool unlike Nirsoft suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the display mode with the built-in `displayswitch.exe /clone` to duplicate your screen, and `displayswitch.exe /extend` to extend your screen.

Then it depends whether you want to add that to the application's startup command, or if you want a program like AHK to wait and listen for that specific application to start

Answer (score 0):

You could write a batch script, calling bot Nirsaoft's [MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) and your application.

1. Line 1: Call *MultiMonitorTool* to set the display to *Duplicate*.
2. Line 2: Call the application.
3. Line 3: Call *MultiMonitorTool* to set the display to *Extend*.

Until the app closes, the *Duplicate* setting is in effect.